# Download finished with wrong size

Tags: android

I am installing  Android SDK and AVD Manager in my eclipse, I am getting this in console:

```
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 96280271 bytes, got 24895488 bytes.
Downloading ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 99621822 bytes, got 49778688 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your download was stopped about 1/4 of the way. Once you start the download, do not close any windows. Keep it running to see if it will download entirely.

If anything. Restart eclipse and see if problem persists.

If it keep disconnecting while downloading you may have an intermittent network connection. Try connecting directly, and not with wireless.